# How to store objects with varying classes (but the same base) in a single variable

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++ and am trying to find a good pattern for having the following:

- A base class that defines several (virtual?) functions and properties.
- Several varying classes that inherit from this base class and override some or all of the virtual functions and work with the parent's properties.
- Then my plan was to have a single variable that can store any one of the classes and call functions defined in the base one. Sometimes I will swap out the object in this variable for one of the others.

Does this seem sensible and how can I store objects like this of varying classes? I was hoping to just be able to define the variable as `BaseClass myCurrentObject;` and then do something like `myCurrentObject = ChildClassA();` or `myCurrentObject = ChildClassB();` etc but it doesn't seem to be that simple!

Comment: It will work fine if you'll use pointers instead of values - like `BaseClass *myCurrentObject = new ChildClassA;` or better `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> myCurrentObject (new ChildClassA);` for more safety (if you have c++11).

Comment: @AlexTelishev Please no - use std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr (or if you have no C++11 the boost equivalents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is exactly polymorphism, so yes, this is reasonable.

As proposed in the comments, you have to use pointers for referencing to the objects, as in

```
BaseClass* obj = new ChildClassA();
obj->call_some_virtual_function(); 
  // ^ Will call the most derived definition of the function
```

Of course, if you are writing any serious program, you should not use plain pointers here. They simply make it too likely that you will sooner or latter forget to delete the old object pointed to by `obj` before assigning a new one to it. But since you said you are new to C++ and might just want to try things out, the above could fine.

The reason why it cannot be as easy as simply writing `BaseClass obj = ChildClassA();` is that this defines `obj` to be an object of type `BaseClass`. But since `ChildClassA` might have more members than `BaseClass`, you cannot store a `ChildClassA` at a spot that was only intended for a `BaseClass` object. You should thus realize that polymorphism requires a variable amount of memory, and this you can only get on the heap.

Comment: Thanks! So as long as i do `delete obj;` before pointing it to a new object I should be good right?

Comment: Yes. Or at least almost: Of course, after you deleted the object you also have to make sure that you point `obj` at a new valid object before using it again. So as a rule of thumb, except at the beginning and end of the program you should always have `delete obj; obj = new Whatever()` as a pair, never just one alone.